# finding correlations in numeric vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab

My input is a simple vector of a kind:

```
vector=[1 2 3 2 3 4 1 1 2];
```

(Numbers only from 1-4), and I want to create a matrix whose rows are all possible two-number combinations (16 rows in this case, for example: row 1 is for 11, row 2 for 12 etc), and has the same number of columns as the vector's length minus one (8).

Each cell in the matrix holds the number of times the specific combination was found in the vector with the specific relative distance- which is the number of the column.
for example:

matrix(1,1)=1 (1 is found one time within a relative distance of 1 to another 1)
matrix(1,6)=1 (1 is found one time within a relative distance of 6 to another 1)
matrix(2,1)=2 (1 is found two times within a relative distance of 1 to another 2)

Does anyone know if matlab has a function that does that? (or close to that?)
(not by looping, using ´strfind´ etc, I know those).

If anyone knows of a specific function I can use please let me know!

Thank you

Comment: it's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you can write that function pretty easily, no?

Comment: Can you write the expected output explicitly instead of describing it with words?

Answer (score 2):

If you were only interested in the number of co-ocurrences, this is, the number of times that two numbers appear together, you could use the Matlab function ´graycomatrix´, which gives the gray level co-ocurrence matrix.

As it is intended to be used with matrices, you should convert your vector into a matrix, for example filling with zeros:

```
vector=zeros(9);
vector(1,:)=[1 2 3 2 3 4 1 1 2];
[glcm] = graycomatrix(vector,'NumLevels',5,'G',[])
```

You would get the following result:

```
glcm =

    64     0     0     0     0
     0     1     2     0     0
     0     0     0     2     0
     0     0     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0
```

You can ignore the first row and column, as they correspond to the value 0:

```
glcm(:,1)=[];
glcm(1,:)=[];
glcm


glcm =

     1     2     0     0
     0     0     2     0
     0     1     0     1
     1     0     0     0
```

Now you have the number of co-ocurrences for each combination. For example, glcm(1,1) gives you the number of times that two 1s appear together, glcm(1,2), the number of times that 1 and 2 appear together...

But I haven't found any function that can do what you are asking, this is, taking into account the distances. So I think that you'll have to do it by looping.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab does not have a function to do that. Looping certainly seems like the most straightforward way to get it done.